# Pandas transform series values until condition is met without for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I asked this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255319/pandas-transform-series-values-until-condition-is-met-without-for-loop) first, but didn't get any response so I am posting it here.

I have a pandas Series contain 0s and 1s. Now I want to convert all the 0s to 1s which come before the first 1, and rest of the 1s to 0s. I can achieve that using the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [0,0,1,0,0,1]
df = pd.Series(a)
flag = True
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  if (df[i]!=1) & flag:
    df[i]=1
  elif flag:
    flag=False
  else:
    df[i]=0
print(df)
```

Final dataframe:

```
[1,1,1,0,0,0]
```

But how can I optimize it? Perhaps by avoiding the for loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can shift values by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with cumulative sum and compare `0` and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (np.where(df.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().eq(0), 1, 0))
[1 1 1 0 0 0]
```

Or convert mask to integers:

```
print (df.shift(fill_value=0).cumsum().eq(0).astype(int))
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
dtype: int32
```